# Odoo 8 new menu item under Settings>technical>email

Tags: email, settings, menuitem, odoo-8

I want to add a new menu item under the parent Settings/Technical/Email but I don't have an idea how, any help pls.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add your menu under `parent="base.menu_email"`, something like this:

```
<menuitem name="your_menu_name" id="your_menu_id" parent="base.menu_email" action="the_action_for_your_menu" />
```

For more details you can review `addons/mail/mail_message_subtype.xml`, I hope this can be helpful for you.